# How to use &nbsb; in react-intl

Tags: reactjs, intl

How can you use `&nbsp;` when using react-intl so control word breaking.
I have a message like Rs. 100,00,000 but it is breaking on Rs.
is there anyway in can write the message as `Rs.&nbsp;100,00,000` 
When I try doing that it displays the Rs. 100,00,000 when the html is rendered

Answer (score 4):

I've put unicode character `\u00a0` just into the text message which suddenly worked :)

Text message: `'Please provide additional information like server logs'`

Message with non breaking space: `'Please provide additional information like server\u00a0logs'`

Answer (score 0):

Using entity number `&#160;` instead of worked for me

reference:[Html Entities W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is good practice to coupling breaking logic with the message (although it is sometimes necessary). In most cases, this might require additional communication later with translators as they are usually unfamiliar with coding practices.

Also, number, currency, and date formatting are not the same in all languages. In case you are striving for perfectionism, maybe you should format these values as well.

If this breaking rule is the same in all your languages, maybe wrapping the localization message with the `div` and setting the `white-space: nowrap` is a cleaner solution.

```
<div style={{ whiteSpace: "nowrap" }}>
  {message}
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can pass the HTML entity as a placeholder.

```
// "message.example": "Rs.{nbsp}100,00,000"
<FormattedMessage id="message.example" values={{ nbsp: <>&nbsp;</> }} />
```